# How to add certificate for https connection

Tags: web-services, https, ssl-certificate

Hi Everyone,
             I have certificate can any one tell me how to add and apply to use ssl connection with java class.I am facing **javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertificateException: No name matching localhost found** exception.

Answer (score -2):

hello everyone i got the ans of my question after a long struggle.
1.For my first exception i used this link http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-ws/java-security-cert-certificateexception-no-name-matching-localhost-found/
2.For my second exception i did not import that my certificate to keystore for that this is the command **sudo /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/keytool -import -file "give full path of certificate" -keystore "/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/security/cacerts" -alias "certificate"**